# How to submit data using Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, post, guzzle

I use Guzzle for calling an API (Fitnet). Everything is ok with GET request, but i've a problem with a POST request. Looks like no data is being sent to the API

My code is :

```
    $contract = array("companyId" => 1,
          "companyName"=> "",
          "contractCreator" => "",
          "contractCurrency"=> "",
          "deliveryAmount"=> 12346,
          "title"=> "blabla7",
          "orderNumber"=> "numéro de commande",
          "upperLimit"=> "",
          "beginDate"=> "10/10/2019",
          "billingDate"=> "10/10/2021",
          "endDate"=> "10/10/2021",
          "businessUnit"=> 0,
          "businessUnitName"=> "",
          "customerId"=> 48,
          "billingMode"=> 2,
          "billingPlanning"=> 0,
          "billingPlanningName"=> "",
          "profitCenter"=> "",
          "status"=> 1,
          "statusName"=> "",
          "description"=> "",
          "billableExpenses"=> true,
          "contractCategoryDesignation"=> "",
          "contractCategoryId"=> 2);
    
    $res = $client->post('https://myurl.fitnetmanager.com/FitnetManager/rest/contracts/create', [
        'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json'],
        'auth' => ['myemail', 'mypassword'],
        'json' => [ 'Contract' => json_encode($contract) ]
    ]);
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance,

F.

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle will encode the data into JSON for you, you should not encode it beforehand.

```php
  $res = $client->post('https://myurl.fitnetmanager.com/FitnetManager/rest/contracts/create', [
        'auth' => ['myemail', 'mypassword'],
        'json' => $contract
    ]);
```

You also don't need to specify the content-type header.

Comment: thank you, but i got the same problem with your code :-/

Comment: what response are you getting from the API ?

Comment: i got "Client error: `POST https://neoweb.fitnetmanager.com/FitnetManager/rest/contracts/create` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: Please specify a company ID"

Comment: `json' => [ 'Contract' => $contract ]` are you sure you need that 'Contract' there? what about `json' => $contract` ?

Comment: I'm glad. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works with :

```
 $res = $client->post('https://myurl.fitnetmanager.com/FitnetManager/rest/contracts/create', [
        'auth' => ['myemail', 'mypassword'],
        'json' => $contract
    ]);
```

Thank you to @formvega :-)